# Slider revolution not scrolling after the last slider ends

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

i am using Slider Revolution on my website and i have a vertical slider which slides for 5 pages with the mouse scroll and once the 5th page is scrolled it takes me back to the first slide. I want it to scroll the page not the slide. you can check it 
here: https://ithobbies.com/main-home/

check the 2nd second of the website it is not the first slider but second slider. once you scroll all 5 pages it takes you back to the first slider whereas it should scroll the page a little bit.
thanks
for example: https://www.sliderrevolution.com/templates/coffee-shop-split-screen-slider/

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the slider "Navigation Options" > "Mouse Wheel Navigation" > and make sure the "Wheel Listener" is set to "On" and **not** "Infinite" as shown in the attached screenshot below

[image]